# Who does Patricia work for?

Tags: plot-explanation, dangerous-mind

In the movie Confessions of a Dangerous Mind, which organization is Patricia working for? Why is she killing the CIA agents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clear implication is that she's a double agent, working for the Soviet Union.

We know from the [film script](http://www.screenplaydb.com/film/scripts/confessions_dangerous_mind.pdf) that she was involved in "[Operation Chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_CHAOS)" (e.g. that she's a CIA agent) but her actions; killing CIA agents, giving away their secrets, etc would strongly suggest that she's either for the Soviets. There's mention of a "mole" earlier in the film. It's almost certain that it's her.

Her motivations and reason for turning (e.g. whether it's for money or for philosophical reasons) are not disclosed in the film but it's pretty clear that she's been working as an undercover agent for a considerable time without a handler and is disillusioned with her life:

> **PATRICIA:** *I don't know. You're sort of cute in a homely way. And it's always lonely when that civilian you're fucking calls out the
>   name off your fake passport.*
>
> **BARRIS:** *"All the information I have about myself is from forged documents."*
>
> **PATRICIA:** *Nabokov.*

Comment: Thanks for that, what was Nabokov about? There was no other mention of that name anywhere else in the movie. Was it Barris' fake name or hers?

Comment: @tivep - It's a quote from Vladimir Nabokov's "Despair". https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Despair_(novel)

Comment: Ah, silly me. I should read books. Thanks for that. Accepted.

Comment: There are other questions I raised about the same film, do see if you can answer them, thanks. - http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dangerous-mind